# Is it possible to allow your camera to be automatically turned on in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas, ip-camera

I am using HTML5 canvas, for a facial detection program. Every time I open the page, Chrome asks me if I want to allow access to my cam. I want to allow it and have Chrome remember so I don't have to keep confirming the prompt. I've already seen [this link](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2693767), but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when Chrome asks you to allow the web app to use camera and microphone. The user must click in the options drop down menu and select "Always allow this site to use this microphone and this camera" instead of clicking on Allow or Deny buttons.

Comment: the option drop down has 1 child only and thats the kind of camera. there is no "Always allow this site to use this microphone and this camera".

Comment: i found the answer. i should has "https://" now my problem is how to put "https://" in localhost!

Comment: You will need an SSL certificate, google how to do it, there are plenty of guides to do this in the web.